# How can I make an invoice in html2pdf so that the height of the page is not complete but depends on the element without affecting its width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to create a pdf invoice with html2pdf js but the problem is that I need the heigth not to be the one that comes by default on the page, but depending on the element the page is cut so it would show me the element as an invoice, I try to flip the page so that the height is smaller, it looks how I want it to look but when printing it on a sheet it takes up all the space, my question is if it can be achieved that in vertical format the page can be cut depending on the height of the element so that the invoice looks like an invoice and that when printing it takes up half of the sheet vertically.

Base code here:

```
 let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  let clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true);
  $(clonedElement).css("display", "block");
  if (clonedElement) {

      const pdfOptions = {
          margin: [0.1, 0.1], 
          filename: pdfName + '.pdf',
          image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas: { scale: 2, scrollX: 0, scrollY: 0 },
          jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
          pagebreak: { avoid: ['tr', 'td','.no-break'] },
      };

      const pdfInstance = html2pdf().from(clonedElement).set(pdfOptions);

      if(type == 2){
        pdfInstance.save().output('dataurlnewwindow');
      }
```

Your answers would help me a lot.
thank you so much

I have tried, as I said before, to flip the sheet but the problem occurs when printing it. I also try to manually change the height of the sheet but since it has a relationship with the width, when I change some of the height the width becomes smaller.